# Loading JSON multiline file into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have asked this similar question for pyspark dataframe. I need to implement something similar using Pandas dataframe. Details of the JSON are in the below link

[Original question consisting of JSON details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870738/loading-json-multiline-file-into-pyspark-dataframe)

I have tried using pd.read_json(), but it fails with the following error

```
import pandas as pd

df_raw = pd.read_json('data.json')

ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

I also tried the option of lines = True but still see some error

```
import pandas as pd

df_raw = pd.read_json('data.json', lines = True)

loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Comment: I'm guessing by multiline you mean one JSON object per line? If so, have you tried `pd.read_json("myfile.json", lines=True)`?

Comment: Yes I have tried and it throws an error. You can see the sample Json file and structure in the above link mentioned. I could load and check the structure using pyspark dataframe. But if I do a pd.read_json() then it fails.

Comment: If it shows an error, you should include the error in your question.  Also, in the other question it seems your JSON is not really in a `{key: value}` structure, it also has metadata, pandas won't be able to deal with that.